# How to Split String in "" after comma (,)

Tags: java

If I have `String string = "[10.10, 20.20, 30.30]";`

How to split into this format `["10.10", "20.20", "30.30"]`

Comment: `string = string.replaceAll("[0-9.-]+", "\"$0\"")` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/o3GTyd/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "[10.10, 20.20, 30.30]";
        String[] arr = string.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = "\"" + arr[i].trim() + "\"";
        }
        String newStr = "[" + String.join(", ", arr) + "]";
        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
["10.10", "20.20", "30.30"]
```

If you have a `String[]` to convert, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] strArr = { "10.10", "20.20", "30.30" };
        System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(strArr));
        strArr = Arrays.stream(strArr).map(s -> "\"" + s + "\"").collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println("After: " + Arrays.toString(strArr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before: [10.10, 20.20, 30.30]
After: ["10.10", "20.20", "30.30"]
```

**[Update]**

Posting the following update based on the requirement mentioned by OP in the comment:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "10.10,20.20,30.30";
        str = "[" + str.replaceAll("[0-9.-]+", "\"$0\"") + "]";
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
["10.10","20.20","30.30"]
```

Comment: Thank you Arvind! If I have String[] string = "[10.10, 20.20, 30.30]"; Then How will split in same format ["10.10", "20.20", "30.30"]

Comment: @Pankaj - I've updated my answer to include this requirement as well. I hope, it helps.

Comment: If we have String str = "10.10,20.20,30.30";  How to get in this format ["10.10","20.20","30.30"]; Thank you

Comment: Actually, I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've posted an update in my answer. Check it and let me know if there is any issue/doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Before splitting, you need to take away the brackets, using `substring`

```
String string = "[10.10, 20.20, 30.30]";
String[] res = string.substring(1, string.length() - 1).split(",\\s");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res)); // [10.10, 20.20, 30.30]
```